# Rendering images using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am developing a web application using Node JS and Socket.IO. Here when I click a button a text in displayed in the browser using sockets so if I open a new window with the browser I can see a text.

**What I am trying to do** is to render some images on my site but I cant find a way of make it work. I tried using simple HTML5 tags but the image was not rendered.

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you all!

```
//HTML

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<ul id="messages"></ul>

<div id="div"></div>

<input type="button" id="button1"  value="Song1">

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script>


var socket = io();


$("#button1").click(function(){

   socket.emit('chat message', "song1");
   $("#div").append("hola");


});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

   $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
   $("#div").append("Message Received"); 

});







</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Java Script

```
//Java Script


var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendfile('index.html');

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){


  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

    io.emit('chat message',"song1");

  });



});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to post some error you got. Do `console.log()` them and. And what is the express,socket.io version you used? How you want to be rendered, where your images will be stored? It would be better if you post your web app folder structure also. (So when the other people come to help you they get more information what's happening to your problem :) )

If you want images to be rendered (*supposed* you stored your images in your server. And you use express 4.x). You need to set a static folder using express. This is also necessary when you want to include css and javascript file.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You can see more of documentation here: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use

FYI. You can use `app.use(express.logger('dev'));` to let express logging for any GET,POST request for you. (I don't quite sure whether express 4.x can still use this or not)